# The Dots of Creation

Tags: cipher, pattern

Along the road less traveled, an abandoned temple lays in ruins. Though it has suffered the wrath of time, its foundation remains strong. And within this place, an inscription remains visible. A series of meaningless dots, yet dots that define all of creation.

[image]

However, this inscription has an error: for what should be four, there is only three.

***What is missing?***

Comment: I'm guessing this has something to do with CMY (Cyan, Magenta, Yellow) and the results of their mix.

Comment: Except some of the Cyan look darker than others so it's possible it's using CMYK but that's just mean. I see 3 that are darker at (1,6) (3,2) (3,9)

Comment: This is a very nice puzzle.  I do wonder how the ancient people who built the temple knew about ******* though!  (I starred out a word to prevent a spoiler.)

Answer (score 17, accepted):

I think the answer is

> Air

Reasoning:

> The pattern spells out "Earth", "Fire" and "Water" in braille, each in different colours with a different colour for any overlaps

Colour explanation:

> Dark Blue dots: "Water" word only
>  Red dots: "Fire" word only
>  Green: "Earth" word only
>  Purple: "Fire" and "Water" words overlapped
>  Yellow: "Earth" and "Fire" words overlapped
>  Light Blue: "Earth" and "Water" overlapped
>  White: "Earth", "Water" and "Fire" words overlapped
>
>  [image]

Therefore, the obvious missing element is

> Air!

Comment: Bulldogg6404 added the diagram. I made a separate edit.

Comment: Ah well, thanks @Bulldogg6404 as well then!

Comment: Indeed, happy to help! Good work, both of you :)